# How to set a range date to Analysis SAP report with a VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, sap-analysis-for-office

I automatized a SAP Analysis report but I don't manage to change the date range

After refreshing the report once, I want to input a date range to this technical field: `ZSOGRDT`.

I usually use this to change a variable but it works for a single value but not for a range.

```
lResult = Application.Run("SAPSetVariable", "ZSOGRDT", sFiscalWeek, "INPUT_STRING", "DS_1")
```

it works when `sFiscalweek` is a single value but I need to put 2 dates in order to have a range of date.

Comment: That's probably because the 2nd parameter of your `SAPSetVariable` function is not a `Range`

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution: the input_string allows to put almost whatever we want and if it complies with the range format, the add-in will interpret it as range.
Hence if sFiscalWeek = "25.03.2019 - 31.03.2019" it will be managed as a range